# Pattern for a function that must be called in first, followed by client code, then a function that must be called last?

Tags: design-patterns, builder

Similar to the [Builder pattern](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrCbqlN4uXg) where a series of functions or code that must be called in a specific order can be called from one public function.

Is there a pattern for when the client must call a specific initializer function first, followed by zero or more client code calls, followed by a deinitializer function last?

I'd like to make it so the client doesn't have to worry about calling (or forgetting to call) the init and deinit functions and can just worry about their own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on language used, you can try with [NVI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom or [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) pattern. There are also some other idioms/patterns tackling with this problem indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

My preference in this situation is to have the client call a single function (which we might call `executeFn()`), with the parameters `f`, which is a function that the client provides, and `fp` which is a way for the the client to provide arguments to `f()` via `executeFn()`. `f()` may also be required to accept arguments provided by `executeFn()`, which have been created in the initialisation step, and to return a value that is used by `executeFn()` in the de-initialisation step.

In Python, for instance:

```
def executeFn (f, fp):
    # do the initalisation here
    i = len(fp)
    f(fp,i)
    # do the de-initalisation here

def myFn (p,i):
    print (i)
    print (p)

executeFn(myFn,"message")
```

... which outputs:

```
7
message
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Simon's answer, you can do delegation instead of hard-coding the operation inside, and depended on language, you can using delegation to be passed.

For example in C# for calling a webservice, which language is able to pass delegation:

```
public class Invoker{
    public ResultClass Invoke(Func<InvokeResultClass, ServiceClass> action){
        ResultClass result;
        using(ServiceClass svc = new ServiceClass()){ //create the service
            InvokeResultClass invokeResult = action(svc);
            // do something with InvokeResultClass and creating ResultClass
        } // dispose it
        return result;
    }
}
```

The consumer:

```
Invoker inv = new Invoker();
ResultClass result = inv.Invoke( svc => svc.CallWebServiceMethod(param1, param2, etc) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) where you have the client call `methodA()` on adapter which implementation is

```
class Adaptee
{
    methodA()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
class Adapter extends Adaptee
{
    methodA()
    {
        mustBeCalledFirst(); //methodB()
        super.methodA(); //from adaptee
        mustBeCalledLast(); //methodC()
    }
}
class Client
{
    Adapter adapter;
    methodA()
    {
        adapter.methodA();
    }
}
```

EDIT

If your methodB() and methodC() is in your client you may add a client interface

```
class Adaptee
{
    methodA()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
class Adapter extends Adaptee
{
    ClientInterface clientInterface;
    public Adapter( ClientInterface clientInterface)
    {
         this.clientInterface = clientInterface ;
    }
    methodA()
    {
        clientInterface.methodB()
        super.methodA(); //from adaptee
        clientInterface.methodC()
    }
}
class Client implements ClientInterface
{
    Adapter adapter;
    methodA()
    {
        adapter.methodA();
    }
    @override
    methodB(){}
    @override
    methodC(){}
}
Interface ClientInterface
{
     methodB();
     methodC();
}
```